# How to apply GDAL polygonize?

Tags: python, gdal, polygonize

I am desperately trying to vectorize raster files in a loop for which I came across GDAL's *polygonize* function (https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html).

However, I don't get the hang of it. To me, the input parameters are cryptic and I failed to figure out the exact commands required for application in Python.

** Edit**

With help of Ben's comment I got to this point:

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import sys

# this allows GDAL to throw Python Exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

#  get raster datasource
src_ds = gdal.Open(inputFilename)
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#  create output datasource
dst_layername = "POLYGONIZED_STUFF"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( outputPath+outputFile )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

GDAL now creates three files:

- filename.dbf (6,451 KB)
- filename.shp (75,929 KB)
- filename.shx (1 KB)

However, when I import the file with GeoPandas (`test = gpd.read_file(outputPath+outputFile)`), the GeoDataFrame is empty.

[image]

Bzw. I am working with this data set: http://www.earthstat.org/harvested-area-yield-175-crops/

Comment: Perhaps this example here will help: http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band

Comment: First, that doc is for the commandline application, not the [gdal.Polygonize](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Polygonize) function. Second, you need to use GDAL to open the raster, GDAL doesn't understand rioxarray or rasterio objects. If you're using rioxarray/rasterio, try rasterio.features.dataset_features or rasterio.features.shapes https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I think I got a step further. I actually manage to create a shape file but it's still not fully working. I've adjusted my question.

Comment: If you get a shapefile after you run your gdal.Polygonize code, then isn't your problem now an issue not with gdal.Polygonize but with opening that file.  Does the shapefile open in a GIS client like QGIS?

Comment: I can open it but the raster band has not been transferred correctly. I guess this is a new issue. Therefore, I will close this question and open a new issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I downloaded the dataset you linked to and tested with the following script- it works ok for me.

In the following script, I left my own paths in for reference but you should of course change them to match your own. I also created a spatial reference system for the output file, as well as a field to write the raster values to (I guess that would suit your goal).

```py
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

in_path = 'C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\GIS Files\\Zipped data\\HarvestedAreaYield175Crops_Geotiff\\HarvestedAreaYield175Crops_Geotiff\\GeoTiff\\oilpalm\\oilpalm_HarvestedAreaHectares.tif'

out_path = 'C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\GIS Files\\Zipped data\\HarvestedAreaYield175Crops_Geotiff\\HarvestedAreaYield175Crops_Geotiff\\GeoTiff\\oilpalm\\oilpalm_HarvestedAreaHectares.shp'

#  get raster datasource
src_ds = gdal.Open( in_path )
#
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
dst_layername = 'oilpalm_HarvestedAreaHectares'
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( out_path )

sp_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
sp_ref.SetFromUserInput('EPSG:4326')

dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = sp_ref )

fld = ogr.FieldDefn("HA", ogr.OFTInteger)
dst_layer.CreateField(fld)
dst_field = dst_layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldIndex("HA")

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, dst_field, [], callback=None )

del src_ds
del dst_ds
```

Afterwards, I loaded the created shapefile in QGIS and deleted all features with 0 value.

The loaded layer looks like this:

[image]

Here, you can see the polygonized layer with transparent fill & labelled with "HA" field value. The selected feature corresponds to the raster pixel with highest value (shown by the Identify tool).

[image]

References:

http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band

[Output field name when using gdal.Polygonize() in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279032/output-field-name-when-using-gdal-polygonize-in-python)

[GDAL polygonize in python creating blank polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92176/gdal-polygonize-in-python-creating-blank-polygon)

Comment: Thank you Ben! This has been a great help! Strangely my kernel crashes each time upon finishing the script but the conversion still seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Stücke, no problem. I admit I just ran this in the QGIS Python console (not as a standalone Python script). I don't think it should make a difference. I don't have time right now but will test later.

Comment: Also worked fine for me run as a Python file from command line in QGIS Python environment.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively it is also possible to use the function `gdal_polygonize` from `osgeo_utils.gdal_polygonize` instead of `polygonize` from `osgeo.gdal` (this is also the function that's documented [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html)), for example:

```
from osgeo_utils.gdal_polygonize import gdal_polygonize

input_fp = "path/to/some/raster.tif"

status_code = gdal_polygonize(
    src_filename=input_fp,
    band_number=1,
    dst_filename=input_fp.replace(".tif", ".geojson"),
    driver_name="GeoJSON"
                )
```

All possible options are:

```
src_filename: Optional[str] = None,
band_number: Union[int, str] = 1,
dst_filename: Optional[str] = None,
driver_name: Optional[str] = None,
dst_layername: Optional[str] = None,
dst_fieldname: Optional[str] = None,
quiet: bool = False,
mask: str = "default",
options: Optional[list] = None,
layer_creation_options: Optional[list] = None,
connectedness8: bool = False,
```